# Laravel - Checking passwords before manually logging in

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm getting problem with manually logging in users using `Auth::loginUsingId`
. Before I do that I need to check if password matches and there is my problem. Password comparision is always returning false;

That's how I save password to DB:

```
    $user = User::create([
        'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password')),
    ]);
```

And that's how I try to compare these two passwords

```
$u = User::where('username', $username)->first();    
$password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
var_dump($u->password == $password);
```

And this is returning false, and I don't know where the problem is.

**EDIT:**
In DB field varchar is 70 char long, hash is 60 characters long

Ok I've noticed: that every time Hash::make gives another string from my password. How it's even possible? I mean how then `Auth::attempt` works?

Comment: The result will include the salt. So, what are the value that you are seeing? https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Hashing/BcryptHasher.php#L21

Comment: Which values do you get exactly for `$u->password` and `$password`when you compare them? Are you sure that the typed password at creation is exactly the same at login? Maybe also check the value of `Hash::make('<typed password>');` and compare it with DB hash value & `Hash::make(Input::get('password'))` at login.

Comment: Also, FFS, use `===` to compare.

Comment: I've updated question, where I checked `Hash::make`

Comment: Because you are asking it to make a new hash (with a new, random salt). Don't you think that you should be using `Hash::check()` instead?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$user = User::where('username', $username)->first();  

if (Hash::check(Input::get('password'), $user->password))
{
    // The passwords match...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try of following

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
``
$user = User::where('username', $username)->first();
$password = Input::get('password');
if (!Hash::check($password, $user->password)) {
  // correct
}
// wrong
```